# Screen scraping with HtmlAgilityPack in C#. Can not retrieve innertext

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, xpathnavigator

I am trying to write an application that gets the xpath of a node in a web browser, and then stores it for scraping later.

I have this for getting the click event of the browser:

```
    private void htmlDocument_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement element = this.wbrBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);

        var savedId = element.Id;
        var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        element.Id = uniqueId;

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(element.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].OuterHtml);
        element.Id = savedId;

        var node = doc.GetElementbyId(uniqueId);
        var xpath = node.XPath;

        lblXpath.Text = xpath;
        lblPrice.Text = GetPrice(xpath);
    }
```

And it "seems" to work.  It does return an xpath of "/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/span[2]"

Now I have this to try and grab the innertext with the xpath that was stored:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(lstURL.Text);
        XPathNavigator docNav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        XPathNavigator node = docNav.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

        if (node != null)
        {
            price = node.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Node was Null!");
        }

        return price;
    }
```

But every time I try the 2nd method, the node is null.  I can't figure out if its a problem with the xpath im retrieving, or the xpath when it tires to scrape the info.  I am guessing the code in one of my methods is wrong but I am having trouble figuring out which one.

Comment: Assuming that you've debugged this thing to make sure that your `doc` has html and your `xpath` is what you want it to be, then this is simply a matter of your xpath not locating what you are looking for. For help, you'll have to post the HTML and the xpath expression from a debugging session to see where the xpath is wrong.

Comment: Its just not finding the element.  However, if I go to chrome and inspect the element, the xpath returned from chrome works "//*[@id="our_price_display"]".  So now I believe that the xpath format I am retrieving is wrong, but I can not find any information on how to get a chrome like xpath.  I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: How do you get the value of "xpath" in the second method?